# Verifying Angular modules version dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I come from Java/Maven environment and have trouble understanding versioning in npm. It seems very fragile.

How to make sure all versions in npm package are correct?
It seems that some parts of *@angular* have versions independent from the rest of Angular packages *(for example **@angular/router**, **@angular/animations**)*
Can wildcards be used like that to keep all modules at correct version?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.*",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.*",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.*",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.*",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.*",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.*",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.*",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.*",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeng": "^2.0.*",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

npm uses [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver):

```
<major>.<minor>.<patch>
```

1. major version upgrade - breaking changes
2. minor version upgrade - non-breaking changes (includes new features)
3. patch version increment - non-breaking, bug fixes to existing functionality

You have control over how versioning is applied (wild cards are not supported).  The symbol in front of the version number denotes how upgrades are applied when applying updates (i.e.  npm update):

```
^1.0.0 : increment to latest minor version. i.e. matches 1.x.x
~1.0.0 : increment to latest patch i.e. matches 1.0.x
 1.0.0 : matches exact version
```

All three upgrade patterns should be non-breaking and backwards-compatible. However, in practice, unintended side-effects do occur, and sometimes a non-breaking change ends up breaking something else. In that case, once the issue is identified, another patch would be applied to ensure backwards compatibility.

Ranges are also supported:

```
>=1.2.7 <1.3.0
```